# An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 51

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am writing code for uploading file using struts. below is the error i am facing,
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 51

```
48:   <img src="images/search.jpg" />
49: </div>
50: <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-   offset-1 visible-lg visible-md">
51:   <html:form action="/dataset">
52:      Dataset <html:file styleClass="form-control"  property="filepath" />
53:      <html:submit value="submit" styleClass="btn btn-sm btn- info" />
54:   </html:form>

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception creating bean of class com.aml.model.DatasetForm: {1}
```

Tell me the solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried with `action="/dataset.do"` ?

Comment: yes, i tried but the problem till persisting

Comment: This link may help you [Creating Bean](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/CannotCreateBean)

Comment: sir, i checked and followed the given link but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my program has successfully ran. The only mistake i done in my project is to include the mismatched java runtime environment in my project. I have installed jdk1.7 and i had used the 1.4 complient version of the facet in my eclipse ide. After changing the java compiler path to 1.4 version in my project properties i got my error cleared in my project. Thank you.